# Zeppelin - Spark Interpreter Unable to create hive table by using CTAS (Create Table as Select ...) statement

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin, livy

I am using Zeppelin and trying to create a hive table from another hive table by using CTAS statement

But my query ends up with error always so the table is not getting created. Have found out few posts which says to modify zeppelin configuration but I cannot change any configuration as I don't have permission to do so.

The query which I had executed and the error that I get are given below :

```
%sql
create table student as select * from student_score
```

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to alter
>   table. Invalid method name: 'alter_table_with_cascade'   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(Hive.java:500)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(Hive.java:484)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadTable(Hive.java:1668)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_14.loadTable(HiveShim.scala:716)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:672)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:672)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:672)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:283)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:229)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:671)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:741)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:739)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:739)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:739)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:323)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.doExecute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:347)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113) 
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateHiveTableAsSelectCommand.run(CreateHiveTableAsSelectCommand.scala:92)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113) 
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:185)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)   ... 47
>   elided Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid
>   method name: 'alter_table_with_cascade'   at
>   org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_alter_table_with_cascade(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1374)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.alter_table_with_cascade(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1358)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:340)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:251)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.alter_table(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(Hive.java:496)
>   ... 93 more

Comment: This looks like logs from the Spark interpreter, not Livy

Comment: But I have used %sql and bound livy interpreter to the paragraph

Comment: @cricket_007 I modified my question as per your comment

Comment: I'm not sure it matters which interpreter you use. My point was that I would expect Livy to appear at least once in the stacktrace otherwise... Are you sure Zeppelin is the problem? Have you tried the same command in the `spark-sql` CLI?

Comment: Nope. I have not tried it in CLI. I am using Zeppelin currently but surprised that even a simple command is not getting executed . Must be a problem with Zeppelin configuration for sure

Comment: Zeppelin doesn't do anything extra to the Spark configuration loaded by `$SPARK_HOME/conf` on the server, as far as I know

Comment: Can you try it in spark shell ? To me it seems spark issue

Comment: @zjffdu Unfortunately I cannot execute it in spark shell as I don't have permission here to do so. We have to use zeppelin

Comment: It sounds like you are using wrong hive metastore version. http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SparkSQL-Could-not-alter-table-in-Spark-1-5-use-HiveContext-td14029.html

Comment: @zjffdu Thank you but any idea how to resolve it in Zeppelin

Comment: Do you specify SPARK_HOME in zeppelin-interpreter ? If not, zeppelin would use the local embedded mode which may have some issues.

Comment: Nope @zjffdu . Can you please let me know more about this property setting.

Comment: See here https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/spark.html#1-export-spark_home